# highcharts, remove alphabetical order

Tags: highcharts, data-visualization, highcharts-ng, column-chart

I'm using highcharts. Here is a screenshot of it.

[image]

The data that I gave are like this:

```
"1": {
      "Peoples": {
          "Very high": 0,
          "High": 3,
          "Moderate": 7,
          "Low": 1,
          "Very low": 1
      }
    }
```

I don't want to change this order, but on the graph, there is an alphabetical order and I want to remove it. I tried to add an index but nothing changes.
Can somebody help me I am stuck

Comment: Highcharts doesn't sort categories and this is not a correct series or data format for Highcharts. Could you post a minimal, verifiable, complete demo? How is your data parsed before using it in Highcharts?

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the complete code for your chart, I would recommend you structure your code as follows.

Define the x-axis labels as categories. They will be arranged precisely as you order them in the `categories` array:

```
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Very high','High','Moderate','Low','Very low']
    },
```

Then, arrange your series data to match the order of the categories:

```
    series: [{
        data: [0,3,7,1,1]
    }]
```

Here's a sample fiddle with your categories and data: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/5c51u9o2/

I hope this helps!

[image]